# How does one write joint p.d.f., when the parameter (e.g. $\theta$) is a vector $\theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$?

Tags: joint-distribution

How does one write joint p.d.f., when the parameter (e.g. $\theta$) is a vector $\theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$? And each $\theta_i$ is meant to correspond like $X_i \sim SomeDistr(\theta_i)$

Assume $X_i$ id.

I've only seen

$f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=f(x_1;\theta)...f(x_n;\theta)$

Does this becomes

$f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=f(x_1;\theta_1)...f(x_n;\theta_n)$ $(*)$

Or

$f(x_1,...,x_n;\theta)=f(x_1;\theta)...f(x_n;\theta), \theta=(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$
?

I think it should become $(*)$

Comment: Neither is correct in general. You are going to have to specify the relationship between $X_i$ and $\lambda$ and the dependence structure between the $X$'s

Comment: Now that you have added the independence assumption, please consider what it means.  Look at the definition of independence and apply it to the definition of likelihood.